# Having troubles using the stack when call my function in IA-32

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

I am having a lot of troubles understanding IA-32 functions (coding on Linux). I need to use the stack to pass and get parameters back from my function. I already managed to do a function that shows 1 char, but I am having troubles making the function that reads said char. I am really just trying to adapt a part of my code that already works outside of a funtion, I read a char and the I print the same char. This is what I am doing:

```
gets_char:

push ebp
mov ebp, esp

; reads 1 char
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, [EBP+8]
mov edx, 1
int 80h

pop ebp
ret
```

And then on my code this is how I call the funtion:

```
push ACC
call gets_char
pop DWORD [ACC]
```

ACC is a 32 bit variable. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Thanks everybody.

Comment: You don't need to `pop dword [ACC]` the function already set it, you are overwriting it. Just discard the argument, e.g. `add esp, 4` or `pop eax` (into an unused register).

Comment: @Jester it's still not working. Like, even when I try to `pop eax` and then try to print eax. I was trying to make some space before calling the function, so then I am able to retrieve the information stored in that space, but I am messing something up at some moment.

Comment: You do not want to print `eax`. The result is written to `ACC`.

Comment: It looks like you are confusing a pointer to the character with the character itself.  As written, ACC should be a one-byte variable (not 32-bit), and when `gets_char` returns, the character read will be stored in that variable.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks! I just changed ACC to a 1 byte variable and things started to work. But I still have a question, like, what is the pop instruction exactly doing then? Like, I was trying to pass parameters using the stack, and the get those parameters using the stack as well, is this what is happening? Because ACC is directly changed inside the function, right? Or am I just messing things up? This is how I am calling the function now: `push ACC call gets_char pop AX`

Comment: Right, when `gets_char` returns, the byte has been stored at label `ACC`.  The stack slot still contains the address of `ACC`; the caller doesn't care about this, it just needs to remove it from the stack.  So what's really needed is to add `4` to register `esp`.  You could simply do `add esp, 4`, but `pop eax` (or any other register) happens to be a shorter instruction.  As a side effect it stores the popped value in a register, but as long as you choose a register that didn't contain anything important, you can just ignore that.

Comment: However `pop AX` is wrong; you must use `pop eax` or another 32-bit register.  Otherwise you are only removing 2 bytes from the stack, and the rest of your program will get very confused.

Comment: Okay, done. So `eax` has my ACC value? But ACC is a byte, is it stored properly? I tried to print the contexts of `eax` by doing `mov [ACC2], eax` and then printing ACC2 (32 bit), but nothing comes out of it. I did:   `mov ebx, 1  mov ecx, ACC2  mov edx, 1   int 80h` . I even tried to change the value in edx, but all I get from it is trash. The thing is that I really need to get the answer by poping it out of the stack.

Comment: Wait, I just changed ACC back to 32 bits and everything kind of started working. Sorry, I'm just really confused. How do I get results back from the stack and not from registers?

Comment: You passed the address of `ACC` and your function used that to access `ACC` directly. Only the constant address was ever on the stack. It is not normal convention to return values via stack. You can change your function that it returns a value via `eax`, that is normal but then you don't even need to pass `ACC` to it. If you know C, what you have coded is basically `get_char(&ACC)`